# Get an index of item from List<int>, when all of items are the same?

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach

Im trying to do foreach for my purposes.

My scenerio looks like this:

**I have a list and it looks like this (with only two values, 255 and 0):**

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){ 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255 };
```

**And a loop:**

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
      if(item == 255)
      {
           counter++; //its simple 'int' varialbe 
           summary += secondList.Contains(item); //its second list with ints
      }
}
```

**My `secondList` looks like this:**

```
static List<int> secondList= new List<int>(){ 128, 1,  2, 64,  0,  4, 32,  16, 8 };
```

What i want to do, is according to index of `item` add value with the same place from `secondList`.

If index of item == 1, i want to set secondList to position "1" too and add its value to `summary` variable.

As i know, `Contains` will return first item as `item` but like you see, in `list` i storage only two values, 255 and 0.

Is it possible to get the index of `item` in `foreach` loop properly?

Comment: If you want the index as well, it's much simpler to use a `for` loop, so the iteration variable is the index, and you access the element *by* index.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I tried this, by how to acces to item? Is it simple `secondList[iterator]`? and it will `== int`? Somtheing like (for example) `secondList[i] = 64`?

Comment: You should really start to use custom classes. Two lists with the same size just to store two related informations are bad practice. Instead use one class with two meaningful properties and put instances of it in a `List<MyFirstCustomClass>`.

Comment: "As i know, `Contains` will return first item as `item`" Contains returns boolean true/false indicating whether the list contains the item or not

Comment: @TimSchmelter nope, it is implementing of alghoritm, only for my educational purposes. If you are intrested in, feel free to look into my repo on GitHub with this project:

[link](https://github.com/michasacuer/KMM-HighPerformance)

Comment: @metadon789 should your algorithm be a binary to decimal conversion? (11010 -> 26)?

Comment: @VladiPavelka in comment above iposted my github repo with this project. You have block diagram there too!

Comment: @metadon789 heheh nice! : ) I've implemented something perhaps similar in the past, [Hilditch thinning](https://github.com/Vladimir-Pavelka/Skeletonization-Thinning) algo

Comment: @VladiPavelka pretty intresting. If u r intrested in this alghoritm, look by these keyword on google:

KMM (older version) thining alghoritm or
K3M (newer version) thining alghoritm. All by proffesor Khalid Saeed from IT University in Bialystok, Poland.

Good think about KMM and K3M - you can end with countour of image only if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use `for` loop.

```
int counter = 0;
int summary = 0;

List<int> list = new List<int>() { 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255 };
List<int> secondList = new List<int>() { 128, 1, 2, 64, 0, 4, 32, 16, 8 };

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] == 255)
    {
        counter++; //its simple 'int' varialbe 
        summary += secondList[i]; //its second list with ints
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either declare a variable that will hold the index , or use a foor loop instead:

```
int idx = 0;
foreach(var item in list)
{
      if(item == 255)
      {
           counter++; //its simple 'int' varialbe 
           summary += secondList[idx];
      }

    idx++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a more functional approach, like

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){ 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255 };
List<int> secondList= new List<int>(){ 128, 1,  2, 64,  0,  4, 32,  16, 8 };

var matches = list.Zip(secondList, Tuple.Create)
                  .Where(t => t.Item1 == 255)
                  .Select(t => t.Item2);

Console.WriteLine(matches.Count());
Console.WriteLine(matches.Sum());
```

Output:

> 5
>   236